# Is it possible to import contacts which are ruled to a folder in the Outlook using Python?

Tags: python, outlook

I want to import contacts from a folder which contains n number of mails to a list using Python, which API I can use for this operation???

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows and Outlook then you can have a look at win32com.client library. Install using `pip install pypiwin32`.

Sample Code:

```
import win32com.client
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI")
inbox = inbox = outlook.GetDefaultFolder(6).Folders.Item("Your_Folder_Name")
messages = inbox.Items
message = messages.GetFirst()
body_content = message.body
print body_content
```

Further you can follow this [How to Read Outlook Emails by Python](https://www.codementor.io/aliacetrefli/how-to-read-outlook-emails-by-python-jkp2ksk95) to achieve your goal. It is a step by step guide for beginners.

Comment: Hi Zaid   Folder.items("Folder Name")...Throwing assertion error.. can you help me out?

Comment: To trace issue, can you post your exact error statement ?